# How to add an item to a Document library from a list column in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list and in one of the columns I'd like to allow the user to attach a document, which then gets sent to a document library.

Is this possible?

I've been able to "lookup" items in the document library from the list column, but I'd like to do the opposite - attach documents from a specific column and have it go to the doc library.

Answer (score 0):

You could create event receiver for this.

Sample code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// An attachment was added to the item.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAttachmentAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAttachmentAdded(properties);
            SPList list = properties.List;
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            SPAttachmentCollection attach = item.Attachments;
            // document library to store attachment as document.
            SPList listDoc = list.ParentWeb.Lists["MyDoc"];
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Attachments.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == item.Attachments.Count - 1)
                {

                    string fileName = attach[i];// this is your last attachment name
                    SPFile file = list.ParentWeb.GetFile(attach.UrlPrefix + fileName);
                    string destFileUrl = listDoc.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileName;
                    SPFile destFile = list.ParentWeb.Files.Add(destFileUrl, file.OpenBinary(), true/*overwrite*/);
                    //get the splistitem of the uploaded file
                    SPListItem finalItem = file.Item;
                    //update a field in the uploaded file if you want 
                    //finalItem[""] = ;
                    //update the list item
                    finalItem.Update();

                }

            }
        }
```